# Does rsync -H convert file to hard link on destination after deduplication on source?

Tags: linux, rsync, deduplication, hardlink

I've got two servers, the second one being synced via rsync every now and then.

I've got some (few thousands ?) of big duplicate files on which I would like to use freedup to spare some space.

If I launch freedup on source, would an rsync -H replace real files on destination with hard links and save space there too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, however have these two considerations present:

1. from freedup [page](http://freedup.org/process.html) "There are neither warranties nor guarantees for freedup working correctly"
2. make sure to use --links as [parameter](https://superuser.com/questions/799354/rsync-and-symbolic-links) for rsync, and not --copy-links or -a because (again from freedup [page](http://freedup.org/process.html)): "If hardlinking is not possible soft links are tried, except one of the paths is not starting at root (but can be forced)"